# Group homomorphism between integers and real

Tags: group-theory, infinite-groups

Is there a non-trivial  homomorphism $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$? I.e., there exists $ a\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(a)\neq0$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT: Suppose that $f(a)\ne 0$, and consider $f\left(\dfrac{a}{2^n}\right)$ for $n\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: how do I know that I can "switch" the limit of the series with the function?

Comment: @Uria: The hint isn’t about taking a limit. The point is that if $f(x)=n$, then $f\left(\dfrac{x}2\right)=\dfrac{n}2$, because $f(y+y)=f(y)+f(y)$.

Comment: @Uria: You’re very welcome.